# How is concurrent modification of a collection detected?

Tags: java, data-structures

We're all familiar with `ConcurrentModificationException` that happens while we try to remove an entry from an iterated collection.

Consider the following faulty code

```
for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : testMap.entrySet()) {
  if(entry.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase("Sample")) {
    testMap.remove(entry.getKey());
  }
}
```

How does Java do that? On a first look, this just a plain for-loop.

Does Java have a special code that marks this for-loop or the collection somehow?

Comment: The for loop here is iterating through the entry set's `iterator()`. It is the same as `for (var iterator = testMap.entrySet().iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); )` and assigning `iterator.next()` tp `entry` in each iteration. The duplicate explains how iterators detect concurrent modification.

Comment: "that happens while we try to remove an entry from an iterated collection." It doesn't happen while you remove the entry: the exception is thrown _after_ you have removed the entry, when you try to move to the next entry in the collection.